# Numpy array of numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector

When I create a numy array of a list of sublists of equal length, it implicitly converts it to a `(len(list), len(sub_list))` 2d array:

```
>>> np.array([[1,2], [1,2]],dtype=object).shape
(2, 2)
```

But when I pass variable length sublists it creates a vector of length `len(list)`:

```
>>> np.array([[1,2], [1,2,3]],dtype=object).shape
(2,)
```

How can I get a vector output when the sublists are the same length (i.e. make the first case behave like the second)?

Comment: Make a (2,) object dtype array, and fill the two elements with lists directly.

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you please add some context? What "behavior" are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @alex_djinn - he wants a np.array of np.arrays, shape=(2,). See my answer below to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...create with `dtype=np.ndarray` instead of `dtype=object`.

Simple example below (with 5 elements):

```
In [1]: arr = np.empty((5,), dtype=np.ndarray)
In [2]: arr.shape
Out[2]: (5,)
    
In [3]: arr[0]=np.array([1,2])
In [4]: arr[1]=np.array([2,3])
In [5]: arr[2]=np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [6]: arr
Out[6]: 
array([array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), None, None],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Setting `dtype=np.ndarray` defaults to `dtype=object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of objects of the desired size, and then set the elements like so:

```py
elements = [np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2])]

arr = np.empty(len(elements), dtype='object')
arr[:] = elements
```

But if you try to cast to an array directly with a list of arrays/lists of the same length, numpy will implicitly convert it into a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([[1,2], [1,2]],dtype=object)[0].shape
```

Comment: I think OP wants a 2-vector where each element of the vector is itself an array/list object.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.