# How do I convert my list into an array of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I convert my list into an array of arrays?
I'm not sure if I used the correct wording, but:

Here's an example:

What I have:

`[[3948,1234,4928,9283,9238]]`

What I am trying to have:

````
[[3948],
 [1234],
 [4928],
 [9283],
 [9238]]```

Thanks Guys!
````

Comment: Just transpose your array.

Comment: What do you mean by "an array of arrays"? You've tagged this with numpy, but your output is just another regular `list` object.

Comment: What did `np.array(alist)` produce?  Do you know about `reshape`?  Or transpose?

Comment: Look at this answer: [Numpy array of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66722455/10462884)

Comment: @kcw78, I don't think he means an object dtype.  It looks more like an array shape issue.

Comment: @hpaulj...yeah, it's not entirely clear. I was working from his question: "_convert my list into an array of arrays_"  His example with `[[...]]` can be a list of lists or an array with 2 axes.

Comment: Dj, as you can see from the comments and answers there's ambiguity in your question.  Is this a list, or 2d (1,4) shape array.  And what is the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
d = np.array([3948,1234,4928,9283,9238])
dd =d.reshape((5,1))
print(dd.shape)
(5, 1)
print(dd)
```

Output

```
[[3948]
 [1234]
 [4928]
 [9283]
 [9238]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine:

```
t = [[3948,1234,4928,9283,9238]]
k = [[i] for i in t[0]]
print(k)
```

**Output**

```
[[3948], [1234], [4928], [9283], [9238]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```py
array_of_arrays = [[num] for num in array]
```

Which creates a new list by going through every value of your previous list and adds [value] to it.